# Swift return different Types from a function

Tags: swift

Completing some old HackerRank challenges.

Some of these appear to be broken - for example "Fair Rations" gives us the following function signature (note: The capital for the parameter is not my fault, it is not changeable within this context.

```
func fairRations(B: [Int]) -> Int {
// Enter code answer code here
    }
```

Now the problem test cases (the details of the problem are not important here) require that we return an

> Int

(i.e. 4) for some test cases, and a

> String

(i.e. "NO") for other tests.

So I need to return either a String, or an Int depending upon my answers. I've tried to return an enum, but I can't make any changes to the HackerRank tests - also returning any

like:

```
func fairRations(B: [Int]) -> Any {
// Enter code answer code here
    }
```

will not work as Any is not implicitly convertible to either a String or an Int.

The HackerRank problem is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fair-rations/problem

To clarify in response to Joakim Danielson, the problem description implies that you can output "NO" to the console, but that is not actually true (see screenshot below).

[image]

Is it possible to have a function that returns both a String and an Int in Swift?

Comment: return value will be `Int` for Successful test cases and `String` for Failure right?

Comment: So, what's the exact context here? `fairRations(B: [Int])` should return an `Int`, `fairRations(B: [String])` should return a `String`, or should `fairRations(B: [Int])` also occasionally return a string?

Comment: @hardikparmar Indeed. The logic defines whether the input is a success or not. I have some code that works, but returns 0 for "Failure" but clearly this will not past any test cases!

Comment: @SanderSaelmans The Signature is func fairRations(B: [Int]) which I would like to try to return EITHER a String or an Int depending upon my internal logic. I cannot change the function that uses this signature

Comment: can you return a tuple like (String, Int)? will that work for your problem statement?

Comment: @hardikparmar Unfortunately a tuple would require changes to the test cases.

Comment: You’re supposed to print NO if the function returns 0, not return a string NO from the function if the result is 0.

Comment: did you try to keep the return value as `Any`? I think `Int` will be converted to `String` and if the return value is "NO" then also it will work.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it does say that. But that is not how it actually works.

Comment: @hardikparmar Any results in a compilation error in that version of Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the function to return a `String`. Keep in mind that integers can be represented as a string as well. The string "4" represents the number 4.

I changed the function to this in hacker rank:

```
func fairRations(B: [Int]) -> String {
    return "4"
}
```

And it passed this test:

[image]

Basically,

- If you want to return an integer `x`, just return `x.description`
- If you want to return NO, just return `"NO"`.

Both of the above values are strings.

Returning a `String` here works because the test calls the `String(...)` initialiser. And if you pass a string to that, it will still create the same string you passed in.

EDIT:

I tried editing the client code and it works. You can just return a `Int?` and do this:

```
if let result = fairRations(B: B) {
    fileHandle.write(String(result).data(using: .utf8)!)
} else {
    fileHandle.write("NO".data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```